# Herstein or Herstein?

Tags: abstract-algebra, book-recommendation

I read somewhere that Herstein would prepare me nicely (abstract algebra-wise) for grad studies. I don't remember where I read it and now that I was about to buy the book I found out that there two Hersteins:

[Topics in Algebra](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0471010901) (Amazon Link)

and

[Abstract Algebra](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0471368792) (Amazon Link)

I wanted to figure out whether one is more advanced than the other or whether one is sequel to the other.

So I looked at both TOCs on Amazon and saw that Topics in Algebra is about 100 pages longer. Then I tried to figure out which one is more advanced by comparing. But it's kind of confusing because for example in just the group theory part, in one book there is a chapter ''Factor groups'' whereas in the other book the chapter is called ''Normal subgroups and Quotient groups''.

Now I don't know much more. So my question is:

> Is one of the two Hersteins a sequel to the other, that is, are they
>   meant to be read in a particular order?

And:

> Is one of them more advanced than the other?

And:

> Is it a good idea to read both?

I cannot tell how much overlap there is.

Comment: *Topics in Algebra* is the more advanced book.  It is the one you will need to master to prepare for graduate work.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**Answers:**

1. Neither book is meant as a sequel, they are independent texts.
2. The more advanced (and more generally well-accepted) book is *Topics in Algebra*.
3. It's always a good idea to read more (especially in mathematics), but generally I would advise (a) to read more than one author and (b) to read something other than Herstein's *Abstract Algebra*.

**Additional comments, respectively:**

1. No further comment.
2. I don't know of any occasion where somebody has referred to an algebra book as "Herstein" and has been referring to *Abstract Algebra* - they always mean *Topics in Algebra*. To add to this point, *Topics in Algebra* is highly recommended on the [Chicago undergraduate mathematics bibliography](https://www.ocf.berkeley.edu/~abhishek/chicmath.htm), while *Abstract Algebra* isn't mentioned.
3. If you're looking towards graduate studies, you might want to check out *Abstract Algebra* by Dummit/Foote instead. If that's too heavy (also, perhaps too hard at this stage), an oft-recommended text is Fraleigh's *A First Course in Abstract Algebra*.

Comment: Thank you very much. This answers my question very well. Would you recommend or not recommend to read both Hersteins?

Comment: If you want to read Herstein, go for *Topics in Algebra*. If you want to read another abstract algebra textbook at the same time, I would recommend reading Herstein's *Topics in Algebra* and Fraleigh's *A First Course in Abstract Algebra* together. They have a lot of overlap of course, but the material is presented very differently by the authors. Good luck!

Comment: I used Fraleigh in a masters level course as an undergrad which greatly helped prepare for graduate school; I've always had Herstein (Topics) around as well. Fraleigh is excellent and surely there is a newer edition than mine, another good one I remember is Gallian.  For first year graduate work maybe Hungerford not Lang!

Answer (score 2):

*Topic in Algebra* by Herstein was published in $1964$ while *Abstract Algebra* was published in $1986$. Most widely *Topics* is considered as a classical book in abstract algebra. *Topics* is I think best for the subject. I don't know they are sequels or not as *Topics* is an advanced book. Very well written and exciting. I think everybody should read *Topics*. I will recommend you to start with *Topics* if you like to.

Answer (score 1):

*Topics in Algebra* is a graduate level text, *Abstract Algebra* is more solidly an undergraduate textbook. Having said that, I found having *Abstract Algebra* around while I was a graduate student was super helpful as a study aid (we were using Dummit & Foote), and is a good preparation for a graduate level course -- but not a replacement for a graduate course or text at all. The writing in *Abstract Algebra* is very approachable and clear, and the problems range from the trivial to the quite challenging. *Topics in Algebra* is *not* a starter book for the topic.